# Trying to display the last index of a item in array Java

Tags: java

I am trying to display the last index of an item in array, an example:

`{6,4,7,3,11,4} Last index of 4 = 5`

I have written this method so far:

```
public int lastIndexOf(int[] nums, int num) {
        int found = 0;
        for (int i = nums.length; i < 0 ; i--) {
            if (nums[i] == num) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;

    }
```

Why does this not work? I am under the impression that you need to start the for loop at the start of the arrays length and then work backwards. I want to be able to use a for loop to do this, I set up a condition if there are no occurrences of the number to return -1 but when I am running this code I always return -1 no matter what numbers I am putting in.

How would I solve this using a for loop?

Comment: You want `i >= 0`, not `i < 0`. The loop is never being entered because the length of an array must be at least 0, so the loop condition must be false.

Comment: @Carcigenicate when I change it to that I get a out of bounds error

Comment: You also need `int i = nums.length - 1`. `nums.length` is out of bounds by one. You're getting that error now because the loop is being entered.

Comment: Why you are starting your loop from end of Array rather then start Index of Array ?, If you want to display end of array, it will easily iterate by traversing it from start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop conditions are not correct. Should be

```
for (int i = nums.length-1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
```

The "i<0" from before prevented it from entering the loop.

But the "i = nums.length" would have given you an Index out of bounds error. Need to subtract by 1 because Arrays are 0 indexed

Answer (score 0):

You can also turn the array into list and use List's `lastIndexOf` method so you don't have to implement yourself.

```
Arrays.asList(nums).lastIndexOf(num)
```

note that `lastIndexOf` return -1 if `num` is not found in `nums`